# Subscription based payments via SEPA payments in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, stripe-payments

Is there any wordpress plugin that makes it possible to sell 'subscriptions' via recurring payments via SEPA payments, preferable via Stripe? I want users to buy a subscription via my website and pay monthly or yearly by SEPA payments.

Greetings,
Laurens

Comment: I believe WooCommerce (https://woocommerce.com/products/stripe/) supports this. If WooCommerce doesn't fit your use case, there are a ton of others you can look into https://stripe.com/partners/apps-and-extensions?q=wordpress

Comment: It looks like none of the stripe partners have SEPA via Stripe as a payment method, except for WooCommerce... All the partners have credit-cards for recurring payments and they all say SEPA is on their roadmap for later updates but it doesn’t seem to be coming. The problem is WooCommerce isn’t really suitable for this site as I just want the user to buy subscriptions from a simple form instead of with a shopping cart and all such.